# Interoperability issue between VC++ (ocx) & VB.NET applications

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++

We are migrating a product from VB6 to VB.NET and facing an issue. 
This product interacts with a function defined in VC++ component (.ocx).

1. VB6 & VB.NET function call:

   result = TestFunc(Param1, Param2, Param3)
2. VC++:
   a) Function definition in .CPP file:
      long TestFunc(long FAR* Param1, const VARIANT FAR& Param2, long Param3) 
       {
       ...
       }

DISP_FUNCTION(Ctrl, "TestFunc", TestFunc, VT_I4, VTS_PI4 VTS_VARIANT VTS_I4)

b) Function signature in .ODL file:
      long TestFunc(long* Param1, VARIANT Param2, long Param3);

c) Function signature in .h(header) file:
      afx_msg long TestFunc(long FAR* Param1,  const VARIANT FAR& Param2, long Param3);

"Param2" in above "TestFunc" is defined as byte array in VB6 & VB.NET.

In VC++, the corresponding type for "Param2" in "TestFunc" is - "const VARIANT FAR& Param2".

In VB6, the byte array values passed gets modified in VC++ "TestFunc" & the modified values are received in VB6 "Param2" variable.

Issue in VB.NET:

In VB.NET, the byte array values passed gets modified in VC++ "TestFunc".
However, the modified values are not transferred from VC++ to VB.NET. The "Param2" variable still has the original values & not the modified values.

Could you please provide us information on how to obtain the modified byte array values in VB.NET from the Variant variable in VC++ component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ODL does not match the function signature, it should have used VARIANT*.  Hard to see how this could have worked in VB6.

Comment: @HansPassant:  We changed the .ODL, .CPP, .H files signature of TestFunc with Param2 as reference.

C++:
.ODL:
long TestFunc(long* Param1, VARIANT* Param2, long Param3);

.CPP:
long TestFunc(long FAR* Param1, VARIANT* Param2, long Param3){}
DISP_FUNCTION(Ctrl, "TestFunc", TestFunc, VT_I4, VTS_PI4 VTS_PVARIANT VTS_I4) 

.H:
afx_msg long TestFunc(long FAR* Param1, VARIANT* Param2, long Param3);
#define VTS_PVARIANT "\x4C" // a 'VARIANT*'      comment continues.........

Comment: @HansPassant:  comment continues.........    VB.NET:
Function declaration:
Public Overridable Function TestFunc(ByRef Param1 As Integer, ByRef Param2 As Object, Param3 As Integer) As Integer

Param2 declaration inside a user defined structure in vb.net: 
Dim Param2() As Byte

Function call:
result = TestFunc(Param1, Param2, Param3)

The function declaration in VB.NET now shows ByRef for Param2.

However, when TestFunc function is called in VB.NET following error occurs:

"Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"

Thanks.